# Does $P=BPP$ say anything about space complexity?

Tags: big-picture, derandomization

There are many streaming algorithms with sublinear randomized space but linear deterministic space. Does $P=BPP$ have anything to do with derandomizing space and more importantly but not related to streaming does derandomizing time have anything to do with $L=RL$?

Comment: Here's a tenuous connection. $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{BPP}$ [implies](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~kabanets/Research/poly.html) some circuit lower bounds. Suitable circuit lower bounds [imply](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dieter/Research/r-gni.html) $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{RL}$. (The two circuit lower bounds are not the same.)